# valgrind produces an error at opening function brace

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm running valgrind on a pretty big project.

One of my classes is indicating an invalid write, but it's at a spot with no code.

The details and memory addresses have been changed to protect the innocent.

I have a function like this:

```
class thing{ 

int record(char *c, int i);

... };

int thing::record(char *c, int i)
{ /* line 601 is here */

static const char *x = __func__;

...

return 1;

};
```

And valgrind gives the following error:

```
==xxx== Invalid write of size 8
==xxx==    at 0xx0FBF48: thing::record(char*, int) (thing.cpp:601)
==xxx==    by 0xx0FB32D: thing::open(std::string, char const*, bool, bool, bool) (thing.cpp:370)
==xxx==    by 0xxE8E02: thing::init() (thing.cpp:698)
==xxx==    by 0xx66AC4B: namespace::subnamespace::otherthing::run() (otherthing.cpp:653)
==xxx==    by 0xx3A53B: main (main.cpp:36)
==xxx==  Address 0xxffeb49958 is on thread 1's stack
==xxx==  in frame #0, created by thing::record(char*, int) (thing.cpp:601)
```

The problem is, there's no code at line 601.
I'm pretty new with valgrind, so if it's something silly please let me know.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Are you sure that the `thing` object is valid? There's no stack corruption somewhere else?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? If so you might want to disable them to see if that helps clarify things.

Comment: A good idea to find out what the problem might be and where it came from is to go back in your source control checkin log, until the error disappears. What differences are there between the error-free checkin and the next one (which added the error)?

Comment: sorry, can't do minimal reproducible - the project is way too big and intertwined.

no optimizations

no way to go back in log - this is legacy code, unchanged for a couple years, first time valgrind is being run on it.  i.e., production is broken.

Comment: is there any malloc() called somewhere? possibility that an int* is allocated with sizeof(int).

Comment: Thanks folks, I will try harder to get MRE's in the future - difficult with my environment but probably doable.

Answer (score 1):

> there's no code at line 601.

Of course there is, there's the opening brace of a function body.

Commonly, the compiler will generate a prologue for non-inlined functions. This is a bit of code that sets up the function's working space, usually saving the caller's stack frame address and reserving a new one for automatic local variables.

Note that this is an implementation detail, and not part of the language.

Valgrind tells you the address written is on a thread's stack, so probably there's something wrong with the stack. Exactly what is impossible to tell from the information shown.

What you can do is: see if you can get more information from valgrind (options affecting stack size, layout, chain length), disassemble your function to see exactly what is happening in that prologue, try using a sanitizer build in addition to valgrind, etc.

Comment: I knew it was at least partly silly.  Thanks.  As I learn more about these tools I will be doing all the stuff you mentioned, thank you.